# node-gyp что это и на что ругается

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

Пытаюсь установить этот пакет в проект коммандой npm i

```
{
  "name": "pulse",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.12",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^6.1.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.3.0",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^5.0.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^6.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.1.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 1 version",
    "> 1%",
    "maintained node versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Выдает вот это

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\79114\Desktop\Course\portfolio\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\79114\Desktop\Course\portfolio\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\79114\\Desktop\\Course\\portfolio\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.17.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\79114\Desktop\Course\portfolio\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\79114\Desktop\Course\portfolio\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\79114\Desktop\Course\portfolio\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\79114\Desktop\Course\portfolio\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\79114\Desktop\Course\portfolio\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\79114\Desktop\Course\portfolio\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:206:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\79114\Desktop\Course\portfolio\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\79114\Desktop\Course\portfolio\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\79114\Desktop\Course\portfolio\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\79114\Desktop\Course\portfolio\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\79114\Desktop\Course\portfolio\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\79114\Desktop\Course\portfolio\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:206:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Python310\python.EXE
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогала смена версии nodejs

```
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.17.1 | win32 | x64
```

Попробуй 18 поставить

Comment: Установил 14 версию, помогло